# Accessing all Advanced Custom Field checkbox values

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible to access all values for an ACF [Checkbox](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/) field available in the ‘Choices’ field settings?

[image]

These values are being used to populate a filter dropdown, so therefore simply associating these values with a singular $post leads to inconsistent results.
i.e. my current approach only works when there are posts associated with the custom field to populate the dropdown:

```php
$courses_fieldObj = get_field_object('course_check');

$courses = $courses_fieldObj['choices'];
foreach ($courses as $value => $label): ?>
```

The [‘options’](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/) argument looked promising, however, this doesn’t seem to make available the ‘Choices’ values.

Solutions outside of ACF’s api (such as WPDB queries suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9451/128906)) also look promising, however, since ACF stores these vals in a serialised array, I am hoping for a simpler solution.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `the_field('yourchoicefield');` this returns all the values with a comma. so then you can simply split on the comma

Comment: @Mederic thanks for your response.

Have tested using _get_field_ in the past (which is believe is much the same as _the_field_, except it stores as opposed to echoing out the values).

By itself, the field seems to only reference the checkbox values for the posts present on the page, as opposed to all of the available values in the field ‘Choices’ setting. When passed the ‘options’ argument, the object doesn’t return any values, i.e:
`$courses = get_field('course_check', 'options');`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The function get_field if i'm not mistaken will work only in the current post. you want to get it for every possible post? is that what you mean? Im sorry I dont really get what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I’ll try to clarify: I am trying to use the fields of the ACF checkbox to populate a dropdown field for a post filter. Having the dropdown being populated based on one post’s fields leads to inconsistent results (as say a post might only be associated with one value of the checkbox, leading to only one option being present in the select dropdown). What I want to do is access the values from the field’s ‘Choices’ setting, so I can get all of the potential values of the checkbox, regardless of which posts are being displayed. Hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

Was not able to solve this issue. I did, however, work around it by instead creating a custom taxonomy (which really suited my use case better), allowing me easy access to all course terms via the *get_terms* function, i.e:

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'courses_tax' );
$courses = get_terms( $args );
```

I can still see scenarios where the need to access all ACF checkbox values outside of a $post context will be required - will leave this question unsolved as this answer doesn’t directly address the issue at hand.